# Swift Run An NSTimer Automatically

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I'm making an app and using NSTimer to make the timer in my app.But I need the NSTimer to run when the scene start.I have two scene in my app a homescreen and the app it's self here is my code viewcontroller.swift (The second scene the first scene in empty) And btw it's my 3 day using swift and i'm in middle school ;).

```
 import UIKit
 var Number = 2
 var Answer = Number * 2
 var score = 0
var scorelabel = "Score: "
var Timer = NSTimer()
var Counter = 10

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var RightAndWrongLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var TimerLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var RightAndWrong: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var ScoreIabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var UserInputAnswer: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Question: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var TimerOut: UIImageView!

var seconds = 0
var timeison = true







@IBAction func ConfirmAnswer(sender: AnyObject) {
    let UserAnswer = Int(UserInputAnswer.text!)
    if UserAnswer == Answer {
        print("Your right")
        Number += 2
        score += 1
        ScoreIabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
        Question.text = "\(Number) x 2"
        UserInputAnswer.text = ""
        Answer = Number * 2
        RightAndWrong.image = UIImage(named: "Label")
        RightAndWrongLabel.hidden = false
        RightAndWrongLabel.text = "Right!"
        RightAndWrongLabel.textColor  = UIColor(red: 0, green: 225, blue: 0, alpha: 1)

    } else {
        UserInputAnswer.text  = ""
        RightAndWrong.image = UIImage(named: "Label")
        RightAndWrongLabel.hidden = false
        RightAndWrongLabel.text = "Wrong!"
        RightAndWrongLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 225, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)



    }



}

func DisplayTimer() {
    Timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target:self, selector: Selector("updateCounter"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}


func updateTimer(){
    TimerLabel.text = String(Counter--)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UserInputAnswer.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
    RightAndWrongLabel.hidden = true

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    3
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Swift 2.x :**

```
func DisplayTimer() {
    Timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target:self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func updateTimer() {
    if Counter != 0 {  TimerLabel.text = "\(Counter -= 1)" 
    } else { 
        Timer.invalidate() 
        // call a game over method here... 
    }
 }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   ... 

     // start the timer when this controller shows up
     DisplayTimer()
     TimerLabel.text = "\(Counter)" 

    ... 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start your timer when the scene loads call DisplayTimer() under 
`override func viewDidLoad()` when the view is loaded

Also if you want to update your label every second, the selector in your NSTimer is calling `updateCounter` not `updateTimer`

Comment: I fixed the error using timer.invalidate() when the var counter == 0

Comment: timer.invalidate removes a timer if one already exist. I thought you wanted to start your timer when the scene loads??

Comment: It's good I let the user answer the question first then the timer starts.(This is an app for 7 - 12 year olds).But that doesn't matter because i'm 12 XD